# relationship between webpack, npm, bower, gulp

Tags: web

I have recently just went in web-development and heard about these tools, I still confusing about it even I done research after, and also I have some questions as well. this is the following research I have done if there are something wrong please correct me.

1. Webpack is replacing bower and gulp
2. Bower was use to manage front end lib(eg: bootstrap), which gulp was use to manage backend lib(eg: backbone.js )
3. In some big project people still use gulp because give more control of the project
4. npm is the package manager for JavaScript.
5. If I want to I can install bootstrap from either npm or bower or gulp.
6. People choose to use bower and not just npm to install bootstrap is because npm does nested dependency tree, which Bower requires a flat dependency tree, which means faster.
7. Webpack replacing bower and gulp is because those are overkilling people's time.
8. The last thing is a question, I saw on youtube people download sass sass(which I understand is a front end thing tool)eg:(npm install gulp gulp-sass --save-dev) in gulp and then not using bower, is that even the the right way to do things? because if yes why do we still need to use use bower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Webpack can be an alternative for gulp. Webpack doesn't do anything Bower does.
2. Bower was often used to manage frontend dependencies (eg, bootstrap), while npm was often used to manage backend dependencies (eg, express).
3. People use gulp because it's worked out for them so far, and the time/effort it takes to learn something else and switch to something else might not be worth it.
4. npm is a package manager for dependencies, but it isn't exclusive to JavaScript dependencies.
5. You can install bootstrap with Bower or npm.
6. Starting with version 3, npm installs everything in a flat hierarchy. You can use npm to manage dependencies that are used on the frontend AND backend, so some people don't see the point in having Bower.
7. Webpack can be an alternative to Gulp, but a lot of people had a hard time learning how to use Webpack.
8. Yes, you would `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`, which installs `gulp-sass` with npm. I imagine `gulp-sass` is a tool that lets you use SASS and Gulp together. You wouldn't use Bower in any of this.